# How can I import .OWL file into Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, owl, data-import, owl-api

I have been playing with Neo4J to get a feel on how easy it is to work with related data. so far I have work with the Neo4J community browser to create nodes and build relationship between them.

I have developed an ontology using protege [a link](http://protege.stanford.edu/)!. Now, that I have a huge ontology file(.owl file). I would like to upload it to Neo4J to perform queries and find potential relationships between nodes.

I would be glad if I get any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact format of your file, and how do you want to model the data in the graph?

Comment: Its in ".owl" format. I would like to view the ontological model in terms of nodes and relationship between them.

Comment: **Exact**, i.e. I want to see the format definition and a sample.

Comment: Michael, provide me your email. I will mail you a sample?

Comment: You might be interested in [map owl to neo4j (java example)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20544598/1281433), [map owl file into neo4j - getOrCreateNodeWithUniqueFactory method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20631257/1281433), and [Mapping from an OWL ontology to Neo4j graph database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16823281/1281433).

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the blog post by Stefanie Wiegand?

http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/08/and-now-for-something-completely.html

There are also some other users on the Neo4j Google Group who work in ontologies / OWL, perhaps good to cross post there?

There are some more approaches:

- http://michaelbloggs.blogspot.de/2013/05/importing-ttl-turtle-ontologies-in-neo4j.html
- http://sujitpal.blogspot.de/2009/05/using-neo4j-to-load-and-query-owl.html

Comment: Thanks for responding Michael. I have been reviewing those links lately. Given, I have less programming experience I am unable to catch up with the blog resources. Would it be possible for you to direct me to a source providing explanation with some screen shots. I am ready to learn an extra bit. Also, I will cross post this on the Neo4J google group.

Comment: I don't know if it's the exact same link, but the first one posted now leads to a 404 - I've done a quick google, and this may be the new-location of that earlier blog: http://neo4j.com/blog/using-owl-with-neo4j/